# "The master browser has received a server announcement from the computer" error in Windows domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-domain

I have a domain environment with Server 2008 and Windows 7. Since a few days I receive the following errors from many clients:

```
The master browser has received a server announcement from the computer "NAME" 
that believes that it is the master browser for the domain on transport  
NetBT_Tcpip_{94647C35-65DD-409E-8566-742867B08735}. 
The master browser is stopping or an election is being forced.
```

Comment: The question is " The master browser..........................being forced"

Answer (score 2):

Uh oh! You might start experiencing NBT name resolution failure. These are names like JOE-PC versus Joe-PC.example.com. It will depend on the program (and whether it will try using DNS first by appending the primary DNS suffix) but it can cause sneaky, intermittent problems.

NetBIOS name resolution works by having no real central authority, unlike DNS. The master browser is chosen by election, and that elected browser serves NBT queries. If there are two master browsers, someone is confused. I wouldn't want to rely on a faulty master browser.

Try setting the appropriate registry flag (isMasterBrowser I believe, I forget where it's at) and see if that clears the issue up.

Comment: Brother I read you article but I am not succeeded that how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

## TCP/IP - verify NetBIOS over TCP/IP is ENABLED!

Diagnostic command:

```
net view
```

test NetBIOS sharing.
alternative BROWSTAT STATUS Windows Support Tools microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15326

```
msiexec /i x:\support\tools\suptools.msi /q addlocal=all command
```

If net view, BROWSTAT STATUS get 6118 error master browser problem.

```
BROWSTAT STATUS
browstat dn
```

get local NETBIOS name table, diagnostic WINS.

```
nbtstat –n
```

Get PDC.

```
browstat GETPDC 1 %USERDOMAIN%
```

Get the master browser machine name.

```
browstat GETMASTER 1 %USERDOMAIN%
```

Checks service state:

```
Wmic service where (Name="browser") get caption, name, startmode, state
sc queryex "browser"
```

If service Computer Browser service disabled, run:

```
sc config "browser" start= auto
sc start "browser"
```

Set in registry:

NetBT param set.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters       
NetNode DWORD 2
NodeType DWORD 8
```

Up master browser priority.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Browser\Parameters
IsDomainMaster=TRUE
MaintainServerList = Yes
```

Reboot.

Install WINS if possible and DNS server.

Set Computer Browser service in other station to manual mode.

Comment: Browstat isn't available for Windows 7 or 2008 R2. I don't know why you've included net view. If the browser service wasn't running it wouldn't log error messages. What does that registry key do?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15326